# When using Spring Security, what is the proper way to obtain attempted login username in a CUSTOM PASSWORD encoder?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jhipster

This is my custom encoder class. I need the username for the hash algorithm located on my database. I am querying a function which will output the hash I need. The problem is I cannot get the ATTEMPTED username that is trying to login. I AM NOT LOOKING FOR CURRENT LOGIN because this is the authorization process before a successful login:

```
public class CustomPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

@Autowired 
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Inject
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {

String hashedPass;
String userLogin;
String encryptedPassword;

sql = "select PasswordHash('?','?') from dual";

hashedPass = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
    sql, new Object[] { userLogin,rawPassword }, String.class);

encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(hashedPass);

return encryptedPassword;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over because you will not wait for an answer...

Comment: You seem to have been confused with my initial question within its context so this question is a clarification of that. In my last question, you assumed I was trying to retrieve a record based on a plain password.... that is such a bad assumption without even reading my question or code, why would anyone even assume grabbing a record based on a plain password like that?

Comment: That is still the same question, if you want to clarify the question edit the original one, don't make a new question.